# wants javascript countdown to continue from where it was even after refresh

Tags: javascript, html

I am designing a javaScript countdown for 3 hours using the below code

```
<div id="timer"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var count = 10800;
var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second

function timer() {
count = count - 1;
if (count == -1) {
    clearInterval(counter);
    return;
}

var seconds = count % 60;
var minutes = Math.floor(count / 60);
var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
minutes %= 60;
hours %= 60;

document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = hours +  "hours "  + minutes +  "minutes and "   + seconds +  "  seconds left to complete this transaction"; // watch for spelling
}
</script>
```

but the only issue I am having here is whenever I refresh the page the countdown starts all over again. I want it to resume from where it stopped.

Comment: read about cookie / session / local storages in JS documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the data into some persistent storage method, such as cookies, the browsers [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), or write data out to an external data source (such as a database through an API). Otherwise the session data is lost between browser refreshes.

For example, if you wanted to use localStorage:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // properties
  var count = 0;
  var counter = null;

  window.onload = function() {
    initCounter();
  };

  function initCounter() {
    // get count from localStorage, or set to initial value of 1000
    count = getLocalStorage('count') || 1000;
    counter = setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second
  }

  function setLocalStorage(key, val) {
    if (window.localStorage) {
      window.localStorage.setItem(key, val);
    }

    return val;
  }

  function getLocalStorage(key) {
    return window.localStorage ? window.localStorage.getItem(key) : '';
  }

  function timer() {
    count = setLocalStorage('count', count - 1);
    if (count == -1) {
      clearInterval(counter);
      return;
    }

    var seconds = count % 60;
    var minutes = Math.floor(count / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    minutes %= 60;
    hours %= 60;

    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = hours +  "hours "  + minutes +  "minutes and "   + seconds +  "  seconds left to complete this transaction"; // watch for spelling
  }
 </script>
 <div id="timer"></div>
```

You can try it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/rcg4mt9x/

Comment: but it not longer working for my 3 hours countdown, even after i change the outcome of the minute to work for three hours, @Calvin Alvin please help check it out

Comment: and i also want it to redirect to another page after the countdown is done.

Comment: If you look inside the function `initCounter()`, you'll see that I set `count = getLocalStorage('count') || 1000;`, So it defaults to 1000 if it does not find a localStorage key for 'count'. You can create a new function such as `resetCount(toCount) { setLocalStorage('count', toCount); }`, and call that whenever you want to reset the count to any value you choose.

Comment: If you want to redirect to a url you can call a function like this: `function    redirectToUrl(url) {
               window.location= url;
}`